# How can I generate JSON schema for list of dataclass with pydantic?

Tags: python, jsonschema, pydantic

I am trying to generate JSON Schema from python data classes that contain lists of other data classes as parameters. I don't really care about any functionality from pydantic other than generating json schema, since I am just using the output to auto-generate a web frontend. So solutions using other libraries are fine.

```py
from typing import List
from dataclasses import dataclass
import pydantic

@dataclass()
class SomeParameters:
    a: int = 5

@dataclass()
class SomeMoreParameters:
    another: List[SomeParameters]

pydantic_cls = pydantic.dataclasses.dataclass(SomeMoreParameters)
schema = pydantic_cls.__pydantic_model__.schema()
```

This code errors with the following stacktrace (you can use  `SKIP_CYTHON=1 pip install --no-cache-dir --no-binary :all: pydantic` to install pydantic so that you can debug into it):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/veith/Projects/job-ui-parametrization/debug.py", line 17, in <module>
    schema = pydantic_cls.__pydantic_model__.schema()
  File "/home/veith/Projects/job-ui-parametrization/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 647, in schema
    s = model_schema(cls, by_alias=by_alias, ref_template=ref_template)
  File "/home/veith/Projects/job-ui-parametrization/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/schema.py", line 185, in model_schema
    m_schema, m_definitions, nested_models = model_process_schema(
  File "/home/veith/Projects/job-ui-parametrization/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/schema.py", line 617, in model_process_schema
    m_schema, m_definitions, nested_models = model_type_schema(
  File "/home/veith/Projects/job-ui-parametrization/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/schema.py", line 658, in model_type_schema
    f_schema, f_definitions, f_nested_models = field_schema(
  File "/home/veith/Projects/job-ui-parametrization/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/schema.py", line 258, in field_schema
    f_schema, f_definitions, f_nested_models = field_type_schema(
  File "/home/veith/Projects/job-ui-parametrization/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/schema.py", line 498, in field_type_schema
    items_schema, f_definitions, f_nested_models = field_singleton_schema(
  File "/home/veith/Projects/job-ui-parametrization/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/schema.py", line 848, in field_singleton_schema
    return field_singleton_sub_fields_schema(
  File "/home/veith/Projects/job-ui-parametrization/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/schema.py", line 736, in field_singleton_sub_fields_schema
    return field_type_schema(
  File "/home/veith/Projects/job-ui-parametrization/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/schema.py", line 563, in field_type_schema
    f_schema, f_definitions, f_nested_models = field_singleton_schema(
  File "/home/veith/Projects/job-ui-parametrization/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/schema.py", line 947, in field_singleton_schema
    raise ValueError(f'Value not declarable with JSON Schema, field: {field}')
ValueError: Value not declarable with JSON Schema, field: name='_another' type=SomeParameters required=True

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Now according to [JSON Schema documentation](https://json-schema.org/learn/miscellaneous-examples.html) an array of things is valid.
The [pydantic documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/dataclasses/) uses list of integers, which also works for me.
I would expect that I can also use custom types in a list. The documentation further states `Nested dataclasses are supported both in dataclasses and normal models.`

Am I doing something wrong/not doing something that I should be doing? Or am I misunderstanding something, and this is actually not allowed?
What are some alternatives if this is the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug introduced with pydantic 1.9.
I have contributed a pull request fixing this issue here:
https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/pull/3819

Comment: The bug is solved in 1.9.1.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting, your code is working for me on Python 3.9.1 (Windows). Just curious, what version of `pydantic` are you using?

Here is code that is working for me. Note you can use `pydantic` drop-in dataclasses to simplify the JSON schema generation a bit.

```py
from typing import List
# from dataclasses import dataclass
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class SomeParameters:
    a: int = 5

@dataclass
class SomeMoreParameters:
    another: List[SomeParameters]

# pydantic_cls = pydantic.dataclasses.dataclass(SomeMoreParameters)
schema = SomeMoreParameters.__pydantic_model__.schema()
print(schema)
```

Output:

```
{'title': 'SomeMoreParameters', 'type': 'object', 'properties': {'another': {'title': 'Another', 'type': 'array', 'items': {'$ref': '#/definitions/SomeParameters'}}}, 'required': ['another'], 'definitions': {'SomeParameters': {'title': 'SomeParameters', 'type': 'object', 'properties': {'a': {'title': 'A', 'default': 5, 'type': 'integer'}}}}}
```

Note: I am using `pydantic==1.8.2`.

Comment: I've ran into the same issue with `pydantic==1.9.0` and the drop-in replacement solves the problem. I hope someone can explain why... or maybe it's just a bug in pyndatic?

Answer (score 1):

On pydantic>=2.5.0 this can be achieved through the mean of `TypeAdapter` (see [doc](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/json_schema/))

```
from typing import List
# from dataclasses import dataclass
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass
from pydantic import TypeAdapter

@dataclass
class SomeParameters:
    a: int = 5

@dataclass
class SomeMoreParameters:
    another: List[SomeParameters]

# pydantic_cls = pydantic.dataclasses.dataclass(SomeMoreParameters)
schema = TypeAdapter(SomeMoreParameters).json_schema()
print(schema)
```

Output

```
{'$defs': {'SomeParameters': {'properties': {'a': {'default': 5, 'title': 'A', 'type': 'integer'}}, 'title': 'SomeParameters', 'type': 'object'}}, 'properties': {'another': {'items': {'$ref': '#/$defs/SomeParameters'}, 'title': 'Another', 'type': 'array'}}, 'required': ['another'], 'title': 'SomeMoreParameters', 'type': 'object'}
```